# Добавление записей в БД с использованием textBox

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

**1. Вариант. Работает.**
При добавлении записей в БД с прописанными перечнем переменных в коде
Код

```
MySqlCommand sqlCom = new MySqlCommand  
("INSERT INTO " + textBox51.Text + // ТАБЛИЦА  
"(" + textBox52.Text + // ПОЛЯ  
") VALUES"  
+ "('"  
+  
pol_2 + "', '" + pol_3 // работает  
+  
"')",  
connection); // РАБОТАЕТ. ПОДСТАВЛЯЕТСЯ значение из переменных  
sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

**2. Вариант. НЕ Работает.**
При добавлении записей в БД с прописанными перечнем переменных в textBox.
В textBox прописываю - **pol_2 + "', '" + pol_3**
Код

```
MySqlCommand sqlCom = new MySqlCommand
                      ("INSERT INTO " + textBox51.Text + // ТАБЛИЦА
                      "(" + textBox52.Text + // ПОЛЯ
                      ") VALUES"
                      + "('"
                      +
                      textBox57.Text  // НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ХХХ
                      +
                      "')",
                      connection); // РАБОТАЕТ. ПОДСТАВЛЯЕТСЯ значение из переменных
                    sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

Прилагаю скин с сообщением об ошибке.

**Вопрос.**

1. Почему не работает 2. Вариант?
2. Как сделать рабочим?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите  динамически сгенерированной текст из sqlCom.CommandText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас где-то ошибка в синтаксисе. Что бы ее найти достаточно в деббагере посмотреть, какой запрос извлекается.
   Скопируйте его в среду с подсветкой синтаксиса и вы сразу увидите ошибку.
2. Не правильно переменные вставлять прямо в код. Используйте параметизированный запрос. Это исключит возможность SQL инъекций.

Comment: Заработало. Что-то с синтаксисом напутал.. ВОПРОСЫ: 1. Как сделать, чтобы подставлялось значение из переменных, а не - " pol_1 + "  "- и " " + pol_2 " ?  2. деббагер. Что такое и как использовать (если можно ссылку)? 3. Параметризированный запрос - если не сложно, может подскажете ссылку какую-нибудь ссылку. или пример..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx